# Get a result in the form of a matrix with mapply in R

Tags: forms, r, matrix

I use `mapply` with a function of mine on two matrices but the end result is a vector. I have tried using `SIMPLIFY = TRUE` with no success.

Is there a way for me to get my results in the form of a matrix without having to structure ?

Thanks in advance.

```
> a=matrix(c(0,2, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0, 3, 5, 0, 4, 0, 0),ncol=4)
> a
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    2    0
[2,]    2    3    0    4
[3,]    0    0    3    0
[4,]    0    3    5    0


> ab=matrix(c(4,2, 0, 7, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 6, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 2),ncol=4)
> ab
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    4    1    2    1
[2,]    2    4    6    2
[3,]    0    5    3    1
[4,]    7    3    7    2
> mapply(l0.0025,a,ab)
 [1] 3.9900 0.0000 0.0000 6.9825 0.0000 0.9975 4.9875 0.0000 
 [9] 0.0000 5.9850 0.0000 1.9950 0.9975 0.0050 0.9975 1.9950
l0.0025 <- function(x, y) { 
      if (x-y >= 0) {0.0025*(x-y)} else {-(1-0.0025)*(x-y)} 
}
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @Matthew Plourde

> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    2    0
[2,]    2    3    0    4
[3,]    0    0    3    0
[4,]    0    3    5    0

> ab
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    4    1    2    1
[2,]    2    4    6    2
[3,]    0    5    3    1
[4,]    7    3    7    2

> mapply(l0.0025,a,ab)
 [1] 3.9900 0.0000 0.0000 6.9825 0.0000 0.9975 4.9875 0.0000 0.0000 5.9850 0.0000 1.9950 0.9975 0.0050 0.9975 1.9950

with l0.0025 <- function(x, y) { if (x-y >= 0) {0.0025*(x-y)} else {-(1-0.0025)*(x-y)} }

Comment: are you kidding me? put it in the question!

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for `mapply`. You get what you want by:

```
l0.0025 <- function(x,y){
    tmp <- x-y
    tmp * ifelse(tmp>0,0.0025,-0.9975)        
}
> l0.0025(a,ab)
       [,1]   [,2]  [,3]   [,4]
[1,] 3.9900 0.0000 0.000 0.9975
[2,] 0.0000 0.9975 5.985 0.0050
[3,] 0.0000 4.9875 0.000 0.9975
[4,] 6.9825 0.0000 1.995 1.9950
```

You have to remember that `ifelse()` is a vectorized way of getting a condition and that operators in R work in a vectorized way. Hence you can construct your calculations in such a way that there's no need for a loop-like structure.

If you want to use mapply, you also have to take into account that it treats matrices as vectors. That's why it doesn't return a matrix.